# Calculus integration problem: $\int \sin^5 (x) \cos^2 (x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

What's the integration of $$\int \sin^5 (x) \cos^2 (x)\,dx?$$

Comment: Share with us what you've tried so we can help you along.

Comment: Similar integral: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902722/evaluate-int-sin3x-cos2xdx/

Answer (score 9):

Hint: Write 
$$
\sin^5(x)\cos^2(x)=(\sin^2(x))^2\cos^2(x)\sin(x).
$$

Now use $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ and do the appropriate change of variable.

This is the general method to integrate functions of the type
$$
\cos^n(x)\sin^m(x)
$$
when one of the integers $n,m$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \sin^5 (x) \cos^2(x) dx $$
$$= \int(\sin^2(x))^2 \cos^2(x) \sin(x) dx$$ 
$$=-\int(1 - \cos^2(x))^2 cos^2(x) (-sin(x) dx) $$

Let $u = \cos(x)$ 
$\implies du = -\sin(x) dx$

$$= -\int(1 - u^2)² u² (du)$$ 
$$= -\int(1 - 2u^2 + u^4) u^2 du $$
$$= -\int(u^2 - 2u^4+ u^6) du$$ 
$$= -\left(\frac{u^3}{3} - \frac{2u^5}{5} + \frac{u^7}{7}\right) + C$$ 
$$= -u^3\left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{2u^2}{5} +\frac{ u^4}{7}\right) + C $$
$$= -\cos^3(x) \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{2\cos^2(x)}{5} + \frac{\cos^4(x)}{7}\right) + C $$
$$= -\cos^3(x)\frac{15\cos^4(x) - 42\cos^2(x) + 35}{105} + C $$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Using trig identities, you can show that:
$$\sin ^5(x) \cos ^2(x)=\frac{5 \sin (x)}{64}+\frac{1}{64} \sin (3
   x)-\frac{3}{64} \sin (5 x)+\frac{1}{64} \sin (7 x)$$

To do this, first use the "Power-reduction formulas" to reduce to get:
$$\sin^5(x)=\frac{10 \sin x - 5 \sin 3 x+ \sin 5 x}{16}$$
$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{1 + \cos (2 x)}{2}$$
And then use:
$$\cos (2 x) \sin (nx) = {{\sin((n+2)x) - \sin((n-2)x)} \over 2}$$

Comment: Could you show how? As I see it now it may as well just be reverse-engineered from the Wolfram Alpha solution. I'm not saying you did this, but I don't know what identities you used to come to this.

Comment: Is it really how you solve the question in general, or is it just to provide a different answer? Just curious.

Comment: @MichaelCorleone - fixed.

Comment: Yes I saw it and upvoted it. Thanks

Comment: @julien - just to provide a different answer of course :)
It's not a very practical way, but it's helpful if the powers are very large, so that you can use general power reduction rules.